# How do I get the TouchSwipe event target

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I have a spiffy css toggle control which I am trying to add swipe support for and I am using the TouchSwipe plugin. The problem is that I don't know how to only affect the element that called it. I have a bunch of toggles on the page and right now they are all triggered instead of just the one I and swiping on. (touchswipe plugin: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/)

For example, this code:

```
/* Toggle */
$('.toggle2').click(function() {
    /* code which switches between toggled on and toggled off */
}).disableSelection().swipe({
    _this: $(this),
    swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData){ 
        if ($('.toggle2').hasClass('on'))
            $('.toggle2').trigger('click');
    },
    swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData){
        if ($('.toggle2').hasClass('off')) alert('n');
            $('.toggle2').trigger('click');
    },
    threshold: 0
});
```

works, but it triggers ALL of my toggles on the page. I tried changing $('.toggle2') to $(event.target) to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do all of your toggles have class `toggle2`? if they do, add another one to the one you want to swipe, and use that class for your swipe script...

Answer (score 0):

Although you're not sharing much of that in your question, looks like all your other toggles have `toggle2` as their class (`<div class="toggle2"></div>`). Add another one to the one you're trying to swipe (`<div class="toggle2 toggle-swipe"></div>`), and use that for your swipe script:

```
$('.toggle-swipe').click(function() {
    /* code which switches between toggled on and toggled off */
}).disableSelection().swipe({
    // ...
});
```